# How do you retrieve the screen size of a device using PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, google-visualization

I'd like to retrieve the exact size of a device screen with my PhoneGap application.  I'm using Googles chart API to retrieve some graphs and I'd like to retrieve larger graphs for tablets and smaller graphs for phones.  Also, I'd like to fit them in the screen whether the device is portrait or landscape.

To use the Google Chart API, I need to send the dimensions of the resulting graph in pixels, so I'll need the device dimensions.

How do I collect this information with phonegap?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the JavaScript parameters:

```
window.innerHeight
window.innerWidth
```

to figure out the display size in pixel.

Answer (score 1):

As this is probably for an HTML application, how come you're not just using JavaScript to get the `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth`, or by measuring the first child of the webpage using `element.offsetWidth` and `element.offsetHeight`?

Thanks,
Kevin